# How can I check if a package is installed and install it if not?

Tags: bash, apt-get

I'm working on a Ubuntu system and currently this is what I'm doing:

```
if ! which command > /dev/null; then
   echo -e "Command not found! Install? (y/n) \c"
   read
   if "$REPLY" = "y"; then
      sudo apt-get install command
   fi
fi
```

Is this what most people would do? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Command names does not always reflect the package name they are belong to. What is you're larger goal? Why don't you simply try to install it, and worst case it won't, since it's already installed.

Comment: Fortunately, apt-get install is idempotent, so it is safe to just run it and not worry about if it is installed or not.

Comment: Related, you should use `command -v <command>`; not `which <command>`. Also see [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639).

Comment: @DavidBaucum Not quite; running install on an already-installed package will upgrade it if it's out of date.  Usually desirable to keep up-to-date for security issues, but could be surprising if stability is desired.

Comment: Also notable: it takes far longer to run an install on an existing package vs check if it is installed by, for example, checking for an entry against a list of installed packages. Like, orders of magnitude longer. It's not a practical solution.

Comment: @DavidBaucum: manually `apt install`ing an already installed package will also mark it as manually installed, a very undesired side-effect if that package was previously set as automatically installed.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

To check if `packagename` was installed, type:

```
dpkg -s <packagename>
```

You can also use `dpkg-query` that has a neater output for your purpose, and accepts wild cards, too.

```
dpkg-query -l <packagename>
```

To find what package owns the `command`, try:

```
dpkg -S `which <command>`
```

For further details, see article *[Find out if package is installed in Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-if-package-is-installed-in-linux/)* and [dpkg cheat sheet](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php).

Comment: If you as a person want this NON-programmatically you can use this information as it stands. However you can't simply rely on return codes here for scripting or the output/lack of output alone for scripting. You would have to scan the output of these commands, limiting their usefulness for this question.

Comment: Oddly enough, I've recently discovered that dpkg-query used to return 1 on a missing package, now ( Ubuntu 12.04 ) returns 0, causing all sorts of trouble on my jenkins build node setup script! dpkg -s returns 0 on package installed, and 1 on package not installed.

Comment: Hey, OP asked for `if` usage. I am also looking for `if` usage.

Comment: @Therealstubot : I'm also using Ubuntu 12.04 and `dpkg -s` does return 1 on missing packages and 0 otherwise, as it should. How was different on earlier (or recent) versions?

Comment: @UpAndAdam can you explain why one can't rely on return codes? I need to use something like this and it appears to work correctly (tested on an installed and an uninstalled package in Ubuntu 16.04) when used in an `if` statement. Is there some scenario in which it isn't reliable?

Comment: @JBentley At least at the time I wrote this and was using it; the return code was not indicative of whether the package was installed or not. It was indicative solely that the dpkg process didn't encounter an error.  This may have changed, and I no longer use a system that uses dpkg on a day to day basis so I can't comment further.  But given that 11 other people seemed to agree with me, I think something along the lines of the return codes being inconsistent or not indicative was indeed the issue

Comment: @JBentley Look at ThorSummoner's comment and point a bit further below on a different answer that quotes my comment which described exactly the scenario I ran into.

Comment: a note:  `dpkg -s` returns zero if a package was installed and then removed - in that case it's `Status: deinstall ok config-files` or similar,  so it's "ok"  -  so to me, this is not a safe test.  `dpkg-query -l` doesnt seem to return a useful result in this case either.

Comment: ```dpkg -s <package> | grep Status``` 

Not the prettiest solution but you can just do a bit of string analysis on the return value for that command if you want a more detailed response.

Answer (score 123):

To be a little more explicit, here's a bit of Bash script that checks for a package and installs it if required. Of course, you can do other things upon finding that the package is missing, such as simply exiting with an error code.

```
REQUIRED_PKG="some-package"
PKG_OK=$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' $REQUIRED_PKG|grep "install ok installed")
echo Checking for $REQUIRED_PKG: $PKG_OK
if [ "" = "$PKG_OK" ]; then
  echo "No $REQUIRED_PKG. Setting up $REQUIRED_PKG."
  sudo apt-get --yes install $REQUIRED_PKG
fi
```

If the script runs within a GUI (e.g., it is a [Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) script), you'll probably want to replace the 'sudo' invocation with a 'gksudo' one.

Comment: `--force-yes` seems a poor idea. From man page: "This is a dangerous option that will cause apt-get to continue without prompting if it is doing something potentially harmful. It should not be used except in very special situations. Using --force-yes can potentially destroy your system!" Using it in a script makes it even worse.

Comment: What does ${Status} mean?

Comment: @SaladHead See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-query.1.html "Package information can be included [in showformat] by inserting variable references to package fields using the syntax “${field[;width]}”." Status is one of those fields.

Comment: In your answer, perhaps explain how and why it works. E.g., what is the intent of `-W --showformat='${Status}`? What does the variable "Status" contain? Or is it literal? Why is it `dpkg-query` when some other answers use `dpkg`? Etc. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: This doesn't account for the possibility that the package may not exist at all.

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau That's unlikely if you're the one writing the script, but should it happen you'll get an appropriate error message from apt-get.

Comment: @Urhixidur A complete algorithm deals with unlikelyhoods. A good answer does not make assumptions about purpose. The problem with relying on an error message from apt-get is that we still don't have a mechanism to tell the calling script that the package does not exist, just a halt with an stdout error. Also, it is significantly slower than checking if the package even exists (need to read package lists, build dependency tree, read state information before not locating the package), so performance could be an issue (especially for automations involving many potentially unknown packages)

Answer (score 110):

This one-liner returns 1 (installed) or 0 (not installed) for the 'nano' package...

```
$(dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' nano 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed")
```

even if the package does not exist or is not available.

The example below installs the 'nano' package if it is not installed...

```
if [ $(dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' nano 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed") -eq 0 ];
then
  apt-get install nano;
fi
```

Comment: My variation on this: `dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' MYPACKAGE | grep -q -P '^install ok installed$'; echo $?`

Comment: @ThorSummoner: care to explain why yours is better?

Comment: @knocte I'm not sure there is an argument to be made about being objectively better. Though I'm confident the verbatim post's one-liner will execute the result output, which I wouldn't want to leave dangling in an answer. The one liner I show exemplifies getting (printing) just the exit code.

Comment: @ThorSummoner You don't need `grep -P` for a simple regex like that.

Comment: @knocte Anything which avoids `grep -c` when the task is not to actually count the number of occurrences is *objectively* better.

Comment: Simpler:  `if ! dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' nano  | grep "ok installed"; then apt install nano; fi` -- No need to use `grep -c`, just use the exit status of `grep`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller If your version was an answer, I would have upvoted it.

Comment: None of these account for the possibility that the package may not be installable/exist - surely that needs to be checked too. Otherwise best case is the script wasting a lot of time waiting to discover that it can't be done.

Answer (score 37):

**`dpkg-query --showformat='${db:Status-Status}'`**

This produces a small output string which is unlikely to change and is easy to compare deterministically without `grep`:

```
pkg=hello
status="$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${db:Status-Status}' "$pkg" 2>&1)"
if [ ! $? = 0 ] || [ ! "$status" = installed ]; then
  sudo apt install $pkg
fi
```

The `$? = 0` check is needed because if you've never installed a package before, and after you remove certain packages such as `hello`, `dpkg-query` exits with status 1 and outputs to stderr:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching hello
```

instead of outputting `not-installed`. The `2>&1` captures that error message too when it comes preventing it from going to the terminal.

For multiple packages:

```
pkgs='hello certbot'
install=false
for pkg in $pkgs; do
  status="$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${db:Status-Status}' "$pkg" 2>&1)"
  if [ ! $? = 0 ] || [ ! "$status" = installed ]; then
    install=true
    break
  fi
done
if "$install"; then
  sudo apt install $pkgs
fi
```

The possible statuses are documented in `man dpkg-query` as:

```
   n = Not-installed
   c = Config-files
   H = Half-installed
   U = Unpacked
   F = Half-configured
   W = Triggers-awaiting
   t = Triggers-pending
   i = Installed
```

The single letter versions are obtainable with `db:Status-Abbrev`, but they come together with the action and error status, so you get 3 characters and would need to cut it.

So I think it is reliable enough to rely on the uncapitalized statuses (`Config-files` vs `config-files`) not changing instead.

**`dpkg -s` exit status**

This unfortunately doesn't do what most users want:

```
pkgs='qemu-user pandoc'
if ! dpkg -s $pkgs >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  sudo apt-get install $pkgs
fi
```

because for some packages, e.g. `certbot`, doing:

```
sudo apt install certbot
sudo apt remove certbot
```

leaves `certbot` in state `config-files`, which means that config files were left in the machine. And in that state, `dpkg -s` still returns `0`, because the package metadata is still kept around so that those config files can be handled more nicely.

To actually make `dpkg -s` return 1 as desired, `--purge` would be needed:

```
sudo apt remove --purge certbot
```

which actually moves it into `not-installed`/`dpkg-query: no packages found matching`.

Note that only certain packages leave config files behind. A simpler package like `hello` goes directly from `installed` to `not-installed` without `--purge`.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.10.

**Python `apt` package**

There is a pre-installed Python 3 package called `apt` in Ubuntu 18.04 which exposes an Python apt interface!

A script that checks if a package is installed and installs it if not can be seen at: [How to install a package using the python-apt API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537390/how-to-install-a-package-using-the-python-apt-api/17538002#17538002)

Here is a copy for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# aptinstall.py

import apt
import sys

pkg_name = "libjs-yui-doc"

cache = apt.cache.Cache()
cache.update()
cache.open()

pkg = cache[pkg_name]
if pkg.is_installed:
    print "{pkg_name} already installed".format(pkg_name=pkg_name)
else:
    pkg.mark_install()

    try:
        cache.commit()
    except Exception, arg:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Sorry, package installation failed [{err}]".format(err=str(arg))
```

**Check if an executable is in `PATH` instead**

See: [How can I check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/22589429#22589429)

**See also**

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/165951/dpkg-get-selections-shows-packages-marked-deinstall
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/423355/how-do-i-check-if-a-package-is-installed-on-my-server

Comment: Ciro, ou can't rely on "dpkg -s" exit code. For example if you "apt installed" a package, then "apt remove" it and tried to "dpkg -s packagename" then you'll notice status: deinstall and exit code zero (as if installed). You have to parse the "dpkg -s" output bro.

Comment: @DmitryShevkoplyas thanks for the report. I could not reproduce on Ubuntu 19.10 with: `sudo apt install hello; dpkg -s hello; echo $?; sudo apt remove hello; dpkg -s hello; echo $?`. Can you provide further details?

Comment: indeed - for your test case with "hello" package "dpkg -s" correctly shows the package as not installed and gives expected exit code "1". But try the same instal/remove check with package "certbot", then you'll see "Status: deinstall ok config-files" as the "dpkg -s" output after your "apt remove certbot" and exit code is incorrectly shows us "0". My wrong assumption was that it is exact case for any other package, but it seems it is not the same for all, which even worse and less predictable. Parse "dpkg -s" you must (c) Yoda   :)

Comment: The information that `dpkg remove package-name` does not result in `dpkg -s package-name` returning `0` is missing in most answers which almost drove me crazy. It actually results in state *deinstalled* instead of just *not installed*! Puhh, Debian is ... peculiar.

Answer (score 12):

Ubuntu added its "Personal Package Archive" (PPA), and PPA packages have a different result.

1. A native [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) repository package is not installed:

   ```
   ~$ dpkg-query -l apache-perl
   ~$ echo $?
   1
   ```
2. A PPA package registered on the host and installed:

   ```
   ~$ dpkg-query -l libreoffice
   ~$ echo $?
   0
   ```
3. A PPA package registered on the host, but not installed:

   ```
   ~$ dpkg-query -l domy-ce
   ~$ echo $?
   0
   ~$ sudo apt-get remove domy-ce
   [sudo] password for user:
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   Package domy-ce is not installed, so not removed
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   ```

Also posted on: *[Test if a package is installed in APT](https://superuser.com/questions/427318/test-if-a-package-is-installed-in-apt/427898)*

Comment: If you install and remove a package, next you use dpkg-query package ; echo $? will be 0 also if the package is not installed.

Answer (score 8):

[UpAndAdam wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/how-to-check-if-package-installed-and-install-it-if-not#comment23339241_1298103):

> However you can't simply rely on return codes here for scripting

In **my** experience you **can** rely on dkpg's exit codes.

The return code of *dpkg -s* is **0** if the package is installed and **1** if it's not, so the simplest solution I found was:

```
dpkg -s <pkg-name> 2>/dev/null >/dev/null || sudo apt-get -y install <pkg-name>
```

It works fine for me...

Comment: After `apt-get remove <package>`, `dpkg -s <package>` still returns 0, even though the package is `deinstalled`

Comment: @ThorSummoner: Conclusion?

Comment: Really short and to the point. Plus good explanation. Thanks rocka84

@ThorSummoner can you clarify your point?

Comment: @KasirBarati that, the return code isn't consistent for uninstalled and deinstalled packages- in both cases the software is missing, but in half the cases the return code indicates the software is missing. i think? its been a while since I've looked at this

Answer (score 7):

I've settled on one based on [Nultyi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19001316/500202):

```
MISSING=$(dpkg --get-selections $PACKAGES 2>&1 | grep -v 'install$' | awk '{ print $6 }')
# Optional check here to skip bothering with apt-get if $MISSING is empty
sudo apt-get install $MISSING
```

Basically, the error message from `dpkg --get-selections` is far easier to parse than most of the others, because it doesn't include statuses like "deinstall".  It also can check multiple packages simultaneously, something you can't do with just error codes.

Explanation/example:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections  python3-venv python3-dev screen build-essential jq
dpkg: no packages found matching python3-venv
dpkg: no packages found matching python3-dev
screen                                          install
build-essential                                 install
dpkg: no packages found matching jq
```

So [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) removes installed packages from the list, and [`awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) pulls the package names out from the error message, resulting in `MISSING='python3-venv python3-dev jq'`, which can be trivially inserted into an install command.

I'm not blindly issuing an `apt-get install $PACKAGES`, because as mentioned in the comments, this can unexpectedly upgrade packages you weren't planning on; not really a good idea for automated processes that are expected to be stable.

Comment: I like this solution. Concise and tests for multiple packages at once. Also, you could make the optional check something as simple as `[[ ! -z $MISSING ]] && sudo apt-get install $MISSING`

Comment: Note that this will miss packages which have been installed and then removed, because the output ends with 'deinstall'. Suggest changing the `grep` argument to `grep -v ' install$'` (note the leading space)

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work pretty well.

```
$ sudo dpkg-query -l | grep <some_package_name> | wc -l
```

- It either returns `0` if not installed or some number `> 0` if installed.

Comment: `grep | wc -l` is an antipattern.  To check if something exists, you want simply `grep -q`.  To actually count occurrences (which is rarely useful in this sort of scenario), use `grep -c`.

Comment: @tripleee So, `dpkg -s zip | grep -c "Package: zip"`? (using zip as sample package)

Comment: @Davdriver That's not exactly what the above does but yes. In a script you probably want `grep -q 'Package: zip'` to return an exit code which indicates whether or not the result was found without printing anything.

Comment: this seems working fine for uninstalled packages too

Answer (score 6):

This will do it. `apt-get --no-upgrade install` is idempotent.

```
sudo apt-get install --no-upgrade command
```

Comment: There are scenarios in which doing an `apt-get install` on a package is undesirable where the package is already installed, even though the command itself is idempotent. In my case, I'm installing a package on a remote system with Ansible's raw module, which will report the system as changed every time if I run `apt-get install` indiscriminately. A conditional solves that problem.

Comment: @JBentley That's a good point. Packages that are installed as part of a dependency will get marked as manually installed, and then will not be removed when it's dependency is removed if you apt-get install it.

Comment: I think you should use `apt-get install --no-upgrade package-name` instead if you want idempotent behavior because plain `install` will upgrade the package if an upgrade is available.

Comment: Good call @MikkoRantalainen

Answer (score 5):

It seems that nowadays `apt-get` has an option `--no-upgrade` that just does what the OP wants:

> `--no-upgrade` Do not upgrade packages. When used in conjunction with install, no-upgrade will prevent packages listed from being upgraded if they are already installed.

Manpage from https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

Therefore you can use

```
apt-get install --no-upgrade package
```

and `package` will be installed only if it's not.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/how-can-i-check-if-a-package-is-installed-and-install-it-if-not/65115318#65115318):

```
#! /bin/bash

installed() {
    return $(dpkg-query -W -f '${Status}\n' "${1}" 2>&1|awk '/ok installed/{print 0;exit}{print 1}')
}

pkgs=(libgl1-mesa-dev xorg-dev vulkan-tools libvulkan-dev vulkan-validationlayers-dev spirv-tools)
missing_pkgs=""

for pkg in ${pkgs[@]}; do
    if ! $(installed $pkg) ; then
        missing_pkgs+=" $pkg"
    fi
done

if [ ! -z "$missing_pkgs" ]; then
    cmd="sudo apt install -y $missing_pkgs"
    echo $cmd
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found all solutions in previous answers can produce a false positive if a package is installed and then removed, yet the installation package remains on the system.

To replicate:

Install package `apt-get install curl` 
Remove package `apt-get remove curl`

Now test the previous answers.

The following command seems to solve this condition:

`dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}\n' curl | head -n1 | awk '{print $3;}' | grep -q '^installed$'`

This will result in a definitive **installed** or **not-installed**.

Comment: not entirely, sadly - other possible results in this case are `config-files` - so I think a final `| grep -q "installed"` is really needed to get a functional exit code status.

Comment: make that `| grep -q '^installed$'`

Comment: Instead of `-f='${Status}\n'` and then piping to awk you can also just use `-f='${db:Status-Status}\n'`.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
apt-cache policy <package_name>
```

If it is not installed, it will show:

```
Installed: none
```

Otherwise it will show:

```
Installed: version
```

Answer (score 4):

I think a one-liner is more elegant:

```
dpkg --verify command || sudo apt-get install command
```

Explanation: apt-get will only be called if dpkg fails to verify a current installation.

From the dpgk man page:

```
EXIT STATUS
       0   The requested action was successfully performed.  Or a check or assertion command returned true.

       1   A check or assertion command returned false.

       2   Fatal or unrecoverable error due to invalid command-line usage, or interactions with the system, such as accesses to the database, memory allocations, etc.
```

Comment: Loved this one liner, for most of the packages that come with a command this seems the best option.

Answer (score 3):

```
$name="rsync"

[ `which $name` ] $$ echo "$name : installed" || sudo apt-get install -y $name
```

Comment: Related, you should use `command -v <command>`; not `which <command>`. Also see [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639).

Comment: why does it output `-bash: [: missing \`]'`

Answer (score 1):

This feature already exists in Ubuntu and Debian, in the **`command-not-found`** package.

Comment: matt@matt-ubuntu:~$ command-not-found
command-not-found: command not found

... lol.

Comment: `command-not-found` is an interactive helper, not a tool to ensure you have the dependencies you want. Of course, the proper way to declare dependencies is to package your software in a Debian package and fill in the `Depends:` declaration in the package's `debian/control` file properly.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, `command-not-found` is not installed by default: *"command-not-found: command not found"*

Answer (score 1):

```
which <command>
if [ $? == 1 ]; then
    <pkg-manager> -y install <command>
fi
```

Comment: Related, you should use `command -v <command>`; not `which <command>`. Also see [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639).

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu, `apt` provides a fairly decent way to do this. Below is an example for Google Chrome:

`apt -qq list google-chrome-stable 2>/dev/null | grep -qE "(installed|upgradeable)" || apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

I'm redirecting error output to null, because `apt` warns against using its "unstable cli". I suspect list package is stable, so I think it's ok to throw this warning away. The -qq makes apt super quiet.

Comment: this won't work properly if something is "upgradable"

Comment: @PawelBarcik good point. I've updated the answer to handle that situation.

Comment: You can use `apt -qq list google-chrome-stable --installed` this way you will only get output if package is installed and you won't need to grep the output.

Comment: Note, that `apt` should not be used in scripts as its output is intended for human consumption and not for scripts, so this could break any time. For scripts there is `apt-get`.

Comment: @josch Thanks for your comment. I mention the warning in my last paragraph. I didn't use apt-get because it didn't provide this feature.

Answer (score 1):

This explicitly prints 0 if installed else 1 using only awk:

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${Status}\n' 'PKG' 2>&1|awk '/ok installed/{print 0;exit}{print 1}'
```

or if you prefer the other way around where 1 means installed and 0 otherwise:

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${Status}\n' 'PKG' 2>&1|awk '/ok installed/{print 1;exit}{print 0}'
```

** replace PKG with your package name

**Convenience function:**

```
installed() {
    return $(dpkg-query -W -f '${Status}\n' "${1}" 2>&1|awk '/ok installed/{print 0;exit}{print 1}')
}


# usage:
installed gcc && echo Yes || echo No

#or

if installed gcc; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

Comment: in cause you want to add more than one pkgs
#! /bin/bash

installed() {
    return $(dpkg-query -W -f '${Status}\n' "${1}" 2>&1|awk '/ok installed/{print 0;exit}{print 1}')
}

pkgs=(xxx libgl1-mesa-dev yyy xorg-dev vulkan-tools libvulkan-dev vulkan-validationlayers-dev spirv-tools vulkan-tools libvulkan-dev vulkan-validationlayers-dev spirv-tools)
missing_pkgs=""
for pkg in ${pkgs[@]}; do
    if ! $(installed $pkg) ; then
        missing_pkgs+=" $pkg"
    fi
done
echo $missing_pkgs
if [ ! -z "$missing_pkgs" ]; then
    cmd="sudo apt install -y $missing_pkgs"
    echo $cmd
fi

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Ubuntu, and you want to do this programmatically(although dpkg variations can also be used but would be more complex to implement), this(`which`) will definitely work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

pkgname=mutt
which $pkgname > /dev/null;isPackage=$?
if [ $isPackage != 0 ];then
        echo "$pkgname not installed"
        sleep 1
        read -r -p "${1:-$pkgname will be installed. Are you sure? [y/N]} " response
        case "$response" in
            [yY][eE][sS]|[yY]) 
                sudo apt-get install $pkgname
                ;;
            *)
                false
                ;;
        esac

else
        echo "$pkgname is installed"
        sleep 1
fi
```

Although for POSIX compatibility, you would want to use `command -v` instead as mentioned in [another similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

In that case,
`which $pkgname > /dev/null` should be replaced by `command -v $pkgname` in the above code sample.

Answer (score 1):

the following is the most simplest way to whether a package is installed or not, just locate whether the package is absent using which command, disgard all errors, and check its exit status

```
which curl >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "curl is installed."
else
    echo "curl is not installed."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This command is the most memorable:

```
dpkg --get-selections <package-name>
```

If it's installed it prints:

> <package-name> install

Otherwise it prints

> No packages found matching <package-name>.

This was tested on Ubuntu 12.04.1 (Precise Pangolin).

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections <package-name>` doesn't set the exit code to non-zero when the package is not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt list [packagename]
```

seems to be the simplest way to do it outside of dpkg and older [apt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software))-* tools.

Comment: It is nice for manual check, but it issues a warning telling that apt is not intended for scripting - in contrast to the apt-* tools.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement when running test locally instead of in Docker. Basically I only wanted to install any .deb files found if they weren't already installed.

```
# If there are .deb files in the folder, then install them
if [ `ls -1 *.deb 2> /dev/null | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
  for file in *.deb; do
    # Only install if not already installed (non-zero exit code)
    dpkg -I ${file} | grep Package: | sed -r 's/ Package:\s+(.*)/\1/g' | xargs dpkg -s
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        dpkg -i ${file}
    fi;
  done;
else
  err "No .deb files found in '$PWD'"
fi
```

I guess the only problem I can see is that it doesn't check the version number of the package so if .deb file is a newer version. Then this wouldn't overwrite the currently installed package.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda based off yours just a little more 'elegant'. Just because I'm bored.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
FOUND=("\033[38;5;10m")
NOTFOUND=("\033[38;5;9m")
PKG="${@:1}"
command ${PKG} &>/dev/null
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "${NOTFOUND}[!] ${PKG} not found [!]"
    echo -e "${NOTFOUND}[!] Would you like to install ${PKG} now ? [!]"
    read -p "[Y/N] >$ " ANSWER
    if [[ ${ANSWER} == [yY] || ${ANSWER} == [yY][eE][sS] ]]; then
        if grep -q "bian" /etc/os-release; then
            sudo apt-get install ${PKG}
        elif grep -q "arch" /etc/os-release; then
            if [[ -f /bin/yay ]] || [[ -f /bin/yaourt ]]; then
                yaourt -S ${PKG} 2>./err || yay -S ${PKG} 2>./err
            else
                sudo pacman -S ${PKG}
            fi
        elif grep -q "fedora" /etc/os-release; then
             sudo dnf install ${PKG}
        else
            echo -e "${NOTFOUND}[!] This script couldn't detect your package manager [!]"
            echo -e "${NOTFOUND}[!] Manually install it [!]"
        fi
    elif [[ ${ANSWER} == [nN] || ${ANSWER} == [nN][oO] ]]; then
        echo -e "${NOTFOUND}[!] Exiting [!]"
    fi
else
    echo -e "${FOUND}[+] ${PKG} found [+]"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers that suggest to use something along the lines of:

```
dpkg-query --showformat '${db:Status-Status}\n' --show $package | grep -q '^installed$'
dpkg-query --showformat '${Status}\n' --show $package | grep -q '^install ok installed$'
```

are correct.

But if you have the package `dpkg-dev` installed and you do not just want to check whether a package is installed but you also:

- want to know whether a package is installed in a certain version
- want to have a package in a certain architecture
- want to see if a virtual package is provided

then you can abuse the `dpkg-checkbuilddeps` tool for this job:

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps -d apt /dev/null
```

This will check whether apt is installed.

The following will check whether apt is installed in at least version 2.3.15 and grep is installed as amd64 and the virtual package `x-window-manager` is provided by some of the installed packages:

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps -d 'apt (>= 2.3.15), grep:amd64, x-window-manager' /dev/null
```

The exit status of dpkg-checkbuilddeps will tell the script whether the dependencies are satisfied or not. Since this method supports passing multiple packages, you only have to run `dpkg-checkbuilddeps` once even if you want to check whether more than one package is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If your package has a command line interface you can check if the package exists before installing it by evaluating the output from calling it's command line tool.

Here's an example with a package called helm.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Call the command for the package silently
helm > /dev/null

# Get the exit code of the last command
command_exit_code="$(echo $?)"

# Run installation if exit code is not equal to 0
if [ "$command_exit_code" -ne "0" ]; then
    # Package does not exist: Do the package installation
else
   echo "Skipping 'helm' installation: Package already exists"
fi;
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the following way:

```sh
which mySQL 2>&1|tee 1> /dev/null
  if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]; then
                echo -e "\e[42m MySQL already installed. Moving on...\e[0m"
        else
        sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
                if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]; then
                        echo -e "\e[42mMy SQL installed\e[0m"
                else
                        echo -e "\e[42Installation failed\e[0m"
                fi
        fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this solution as I find it most straightforward.

```
function must_install(){
   return "$(apt -qq list $var --installed 2> /dev/null |wc -l)"
}

function install_if() {
    unset install
    for var in "$@"
    do
        if $(must_install $var)
        then
            install+="${var} "
        fi
    done
    if [ -n "$install" ];
    then
        sudo apt-get install -qy $install
    fi
}
```

The neat thing is, `must_install` returns 1 or 0 which is then interpreted as true or false from the calling `if`, so we don't need any `test` using `[]`.

`install_if` takes any number of packages separated by space.

The problem is `apt` is not meant to be used in scripts, so this might stop working at any time. 8)

Answer (score -1):

All the answers are good but seem to be complex for beginners like myself to understand. so here is the solution that worked for me. My Linux environment is centOS but can't confirm it works for all distributions

```
PACKAGE_NAME=${PACKAGE_NAME:-node}

if ! command -v $PACKAGE_NAME > /dev/null; then
    echo "Installing $PACKAGE_NAME ..."
else
    echo "$PACKAGE_NAME already installed"
fi
```