# In Fabric, how can I check if a Debian or Ubuntu package exists and install it if it does not?

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian, fabric

I required this to quickly install memcached as part of a Fabric script setting up test servers. Figured I'd record it here for future reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pieced this together from this [superuser comment](https://superuser.com/questions/427318/#comment490784_427339) and this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439058/1093087). (Note: I'm running as `root` rather than using `sudo`):

```
def package_installed(pkg_name):
    """ref: http:superuser.com/questions/427318/#comment490784_427339"""
    cmd_f = 'dpkg-query -l "%s" | grep -q ^.i'
    cmd = cmd_f % (pkg_name)
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        result = run(cmd)
    return result.succeeded

def yes_install(pkg_name):
    """ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439058/1093087"""
    run('apt-get --force-yes --yes install %s' % (pkg_name))

def make_sure_memcached_is_installed_and_running():
    if not package_installed('memcached'):
        yes_install('memcached')
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        run('/etc/init.d/memcached restart', pty=False)
```

Comment: Very nice, this is exactly what I'm trying to do. Have you got any Fabfile on github or anything I can learn from? Cheers in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Fabtools](http://fabtools.readthedocs.io/en/0.19.0/) is a very useful Python module that I add to all my Fabric projects.

It has a method [deb.is_installed](https://github.com/fabtools/fabtools/blob/master/fabtools/deb.py#L39-L51) that checks if a Debian package is installed. It's nice to have this standard method across all my projects, and Fabtools features a few other useful package management helpers that you might enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

As to check if a package is installed (running it locally for testing purpose)

```
import re

def is_package_installed(pkgname):
    output = local('dpkg -s {}'.format(pkgname), capture=True)
    match = re.search(r'Status: (\w+.)*', output)
    if match and 'installed' in match.group(0).lower():
        return True
    return False
```