# how to control a shell script loop with: 'dpkg -s pv | grep Status'

Tags: bash, grep, dpkg

coding virgin needs help please - once package pv is installed this code doing always does `else` rather than `then`. Why?

```
# First check if pv package is installed, if not, install it first
PACKAGESTATUS=`dpkg -s pv | grep Status`;

if [[ $PACKAGESTATUS == S* ]]
   then
      echo "Package 'pv' is installed."
   else
      echo "Package 'pv' is NOT installed."
      echo "Installing package 'pv'. Please wait..."
      apt-get -y install pv
fi
```

nb it is part of a backup script that backs up a raspberry pi running Raspbian wheezy `raspbian/2013-02-09` and pv is version `1.2.0` and the author is unavailable.

Thanks.

Comment: What does `dpkg -s pv | grep Status` print?

Comment: Package: pv Status: install ok installed blah-blah & so on

Comment: OK so `if [[ $PACKAGESTATUS == S* ]]` will be true just if `$PACKAGESTATUS` starts with `S`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/check-if-a-package-is-installed-and-then-install-it-if-its-not

Comment: Yes I suspected that AND it doesn't work either. Thx for the link - solution works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of capturing the output of the `dpkg | grep` pipeline, just check its exit status:

```
if dpkg -s pv | grep -q Status; then
   then
      echo "Package 'pv' is installed."
   else
      echo "Package 'pv' is NOT installed."
      echo "Installing package 'pv'. Please wait..."
      apt-get -y install pv
fi
```

The `-q` option to `grep` is used to suppress the output of any matched lines, since you don't need to see them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a minor syntax error in chepners answer, due to the double 'then'.

I had better luck with this version

```
if `dpkg -s pv | grep -q Status;`
   then
      echo "Package 'pv' is installed."
   else
      echo "Package 'pv' is NOT installed."
      echo "Installing package 'pv'. Please wait..."
      apt-get -y install pv
fi
```